# merging in YAML aliases

Tags: yaml

In YAML is there a way to merge values equivalent to this:

```
engine: &engine1
  cylinders: 4
  capacity: 1000

car1:
  engine: *engine1
  <<: capacity: 1400 

car2:
  engine: *engine1
  <<: capacity: 1600
```

This syntax doesn't work but is there a way to do it? I.e. override the capacity of the engine in different places?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

YAML does not support this. The [deprecated* merge key](http://yaml.org/type/merge.html), which is an optional feature supported by some processors, does:

```
engine: &engine1
  cylinders: 4
  capacity: 1000

car1:
  engine:
    <<: *engine1
    capacity: 1400 

car2:
  engine:
    <<: *engine1
    capacity: 1600
```

*deprecated because it is only defined for YAML 1.1 and was not updated for YAML 1.2.